# Accessing fields in a Queryset from a ManytoManyFIeld

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, manytomanyfield

Pretty new to Django and models and I am trying to make a wishlist where people can add to the wishlist an then view what is in their wishlist by clicking on the link to wishlist. I created a separate model for the wishlist that has a foreignfield of the user and then a many to many field  for the items they want to add to the wish list. For right now i am trying to view the wishlist that i created for the user using the admin view in Django.

The problem that i am having is that when I try to print their wishlist to the template the below comes up on the page.

`<QuerySet [<listings: item: Nimbus, description:this is the nimbus something at a price of 300 and url optional(https://www.google.com/ with a category of )>, <listings: item: broom, description:this is a broom stick at a price of 223 and url optional(www.youtube.com with a category of broom)>, <listings: item: wand, description:this is a wand at a price of 3020 and url optional(www.twitter.com with a category of sales)>]>`

What i ideally want is the query set to be split such that the two listings and their information would be on seperate lines on the the html page when i iterate through then the items based on the user. I know it must be from the string representation that i have set up on the model itself but don't know how to manage to accomplish this. I trie .all,.values,.values_list,.prefetch_related, and i still get the same outcome when i go to page and or not iterable

if anything what would be nice is to have access to the the item,description, and price and print that onto the page for every item in the wishlist.

is this possible to do or is my approach wrong and should the wishlist be added to one of the other forms but i think this should work somehow. Don't know if i am close or there is something i am missing in one of my files or need to create a new separate view.

code below:

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class listings(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    url = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"item: {self.item}, description:{self.description} at a price of {self.price} and url optional({self.url} with a category of {self.category})"
        

class bids(models.Model):
    desired = models.ForeignKey(listings,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="desired",null=True)
    bid = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.desired} Bid: {self.bid}"


class comments(models.Model):
    
    information = models.ForeignKey(listings,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name ="Review",null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"title {self.title} Comment: {self.comment}"

class wl(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User ,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="users")
    product = models.ManyToManyField(listings, related_name="item_wished")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.product.all()}"
```

views.py

```
def watch_list(request):


    user = wl.objects.filter(user_id = request.user.id).prefetch_related('product')
    
    return render(request, 'auctions/wishlist.html',{
        'wishes': user
    })
```

html template

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>Active Listings</h2>
    {% for i in wishes.all %}

    
        <li> {{ i }} <li>

    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. Try tweaking your template a bit with structure, maybe an HTML table:

```html
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>Active Listings</h2>

    <table>
    {% for w in wishes %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ w.pk }}</td>
            <td>{{ w.product.item }}</td>
            <td>{{ w.product.description }}</td>
            <td>{{ w.product.price }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: this doesn't work when i add the other fields in only the pk field works but when i try to do the other fields like w.product.item it goes blank and then nothing shows. do you think i just need to rearrange my code somehow. .

Answer (score 0):

The query would return all wl objects. With:

```
{% for w in wishes %}
```

You iterate over all wl objects. Each "w" has "product" field which is a Many to many relation - it contains multiple objects and needs to be iterated again:

```
{% for each_wl in wishes %}
     {% for each_product in each_wl %}
           {{ each_product.item }}
```

Also, name your variables/Classes to something more verbose.